# Loading images with webview from specific floder

Tags: android, image, webview

Hi i making a program that lodes images that are in a folder.(path is sdcard/scheduler/pic.jpg).
I what to load this picture and display it. My picture should be able to zoom. So i used the web view to display image. The code is below

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

         mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

  String imagePath = "file:/sdcard/Schedular/233322.jpg";
          String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
          mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html","utf-8");
```

the problem this code dont    load the image. It only gives the white screen. I think it is a problem with the path. Please give a solution..

Answer (score 0):

You give wrong path to the image. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will give you the sdcard path. Form this start point you should build the path to your image.